# How do you specify that a FreeBSD Makefile place the objects (*.o) into a different directory?

Tags: makefile, freebsd, bsd

If I have some source files in another directory and I want to make some libraries using the source files, I want to have the *.o, *.po, and *.So files in the local directory.  It isn't clear how to accomplish this.  The transformation rules in bsd.lib.mk always point the .o into the source directory.

How do I get the results of the ${CC} -c to be in the local directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file bsd.lib.mk inclused bsd.obj.mak, so you can use the MAKEOBJDIR environment variable.

**Edit**: If you cannot control how make is called, then *don't*  use bsd.lib.mk and make explicit dependencies in your Makefile;

```
foo.o: ../bar/foo.c
```

Comment: using env MAKEOBJDIR=. works, but I am not allowed to change the way the make is invoked within our build system.  Any other ideas?